# Energy stored in a capacitor vs Work that the battery does

Tags: electric-circuits, work, electrical-resistance, capacitance, batteries

Say we have a battery at a fixed voltage of $V$ charging a capacitor with capacitance $C$.

When the capacitor is fully charged, the energy stored in it will be $\frac{1}{2}QV$, where $V$ is the final voltage of the capacitor (and the voltage of the battery).

However, I'm a little confused as to the work the battery does...

To me, it seems that if the battery pushed $Q$ onto the capacitor, and the voltage of the battery is $V$, it must've done $QV$ of work, which means that the energy stored in the capacitor only accounts for half of it.

Where did the rest of the work the battery did go?

Comment: If you use the search engine for this website you will find a more detailed explanation of the fact that the rest of the energy is dissipated as heat in the resistance which is in the circuit (and electromagnetic radiation which is emitted because the the accelerating unbound mobile charges in the circuit).

Comment: @Farcher thank you. Could you pherhaps link that answer? I can't find it....Thanks again.

Comment: @JoshuaRonis Check this out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_capacitor_paradox Its the same idea that Farcher pointed out, but  using one capacitor to charge another.

Comment: A very detailed paper [A capacitor paradox by Kirk T McDonald](https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0312031.pdf) and from this website [Energy lost in capacitors](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/400115/energy-lost-in-capacitors/400140#400140).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens to half of the energy in a circuit with a capacitor?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/187774/)

Answer (score 0):

When the battery 'charges' the capacitor, it overshoots by a factor of $\frac 12 CV$. This produced a [ringing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringing_%28signal%29) signal which is absorbed by the wire. Eventually, this extra energy is dissipated in the impedance of the circuit. Hence the extra energy from the battery is lost as heat.